# Can I get two value in a select option tag, then call it in a servlet?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Here I want to get 2 option value, the project.id, and project.name

```
<select name="project" id="project">
            <option value="0" Selected>Select Project</option>
            <c:forEach var="project" items="${project}">
            <option value="${project.id project.name}">${project.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
```

and then in my servlet, I want it to be like this, is this possible?

```
int projectId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("project"));
int projectName = request.getParameter("project");
```

how do I do this?

Comment: It is possible. You could do something like <option value="${project.id}|${project.name}">  in your form.  In your Servlet, you would have parse the String. String project = request.getParameter("project");   String idString = project.substring(0, project.indexOf("|");    String projectName = project.substring(project.indexOf("|") + 1, project.length() - 1 ); Or something like that.

Comment: its not working, im having error:

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: Thank you my friend, its working already!

Comment: You could post your working code as a solution below here.

Comment: I did it wrong.  It is easier to use  String projectName = project.substring(project.indexOf("|") + 1);

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the value in option by using the seperator. Now at servlet end, use split function to seperate the values and use them.
check this answer : [split string function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java).

Or, you can use javascript to do so,
for that you have to take two other hidden inputs to pass values.
check the script :

```js
function splitvalue(){
 var optval=document.getElementById("instno").value;
 var valarray=optval.split(',');
 
 for(var i=0;i<valarray.length;i++){
  document.getElementById("number").value=valarray[0];
  document.getElementById("text").value=valarray[1];
 }
}
```

```html
<select id="instno" name="instno" onchange="splitvalue();">
<option value="1,abc">abc</option>
  <option value="2,xyz">xyz</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="number" name="number"/>
<input type="text" id="text" name="text"/>
```

Here in place of input text, you can use input type="hidden" to hide inputs. and pass these to servlet instead of select option values.